# How to handle exception thrown from ExceptionHandler in controller with ExceptionHandler in ControllerAdvice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, spring-aop

I have custom Exceptions extending Exception (MyException1, MyException2, MyException3)

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    /*
       Method throwing MyException1
       Method throwing MyException2
       Method throwing MyException3
    */

    @ExceptionHandler(MyException1.class)
    public void handleMyException1(Exception ex){
        //Do something
        throw ex;
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(MyException2.class)
    public void handleMyException2(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Exception Logged inside Controller")
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class MyGlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public void handleAllException(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Exception logged Outside Controller");
    }
}
```

```
My Intention: To log MyException1 from controller advice
              To log MyException2 inside handler in controller itself
              To log MyException3 from controller advice
MyException2 and MyException3 are working as intended but MyException1 fails with 
"Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method .....handleMyException1"
```

Comment: If you want to handle MyException1 from MyGlobalExceptionHandler then why are you handling it in MyController? Why not just put, in handleAllException, a "if (ex instanceof MyException1) ..."

Comment: For "Do something"
It is specific to MyException1 created from MyController. Then it is similar to other MyException1 created from any other controller and safe to handle in Global Advice.
Also according to my understanding spring should look at ControllerAdvice if exception was not served inside controller. Which didnt happen, so wondering what I did wrong here?

I think the code will be more clean this way as controller specific logic will reside in controller's handler itself

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. Spring expects exception handlers to consume the exception. You could always catch MyException1 in MyController and wrap it in a new class, eg. MyControllerMyException1, then handle that in your exception handler.

Comment: Isnt it better to create instance of ControllerAdvice's class and call handleAllException manually?
This might be a resolution but looking for something where spring handles it for me by looking at global advice (ControllerAdvice)

Comment: You could certainly do that. Another approach would be to let MyGlobalExceptionHandler handle it; check the stacktrace to see if it came from MyController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick one of the following options for your exception handling:

**Option(1)** : Remove `@ExceptionHandler(MyException1.class)` method from Controller so that it will be automatically handled by `MyGlobalExceptionHandler`.

**Option(2)** : Create `MyException4` (which is a Wrapper for `MyException1` with added information) & throw it from Controller as shown below:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    /*
       Method throwing MyException1
       Method throwing MyException2
       Method throwing MyException3
    */

    @ExceptionHandler(MyException1.class)
    public void handleMyException1(Exception ex){
         //MyException4 exe4 = new MyException4();
        // Add the required details to it
        throw exe4;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MyException2.class)
    public void handleMyException2(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Exception Logged inside Controller")
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class MyGlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public void handleAllException(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Exception logged Outside Controller");
    }
}
```

**P.S.:** I did not add Option(3) here, which is manually invoking `MyGlobalExceptionHandler`'s `handleAllException()` as It is not a good practice. Rather you should simply throw the exception and the `@ExceptionHandler` will take care automatically.

One more problem with the manual invocation is that at some point of time in future, it will be problematic to debug the exceptions as some of your flows manually call `MyGlobalExceptionHandler` and some flows are called by the framework.

Comment: Option 2 not work for me. I ended up wrapping and  throw a new exception in the catch of a normal controller method (@GetMapping) and catch again in a global handler to build apropiate response to the client.

I found this:

...the delegation to the chain of HandlerExceptionResolver has already been taken place and it will not be executed again. If this exception would trigger another exception handling dispatch it could cause exception cycles.
 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728492/spring-boot-exception-handler-throw-an-exception