# Spring boot exception handler : throw an exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, error-handling

Using this works fine

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@ExceptionHandler(value = IoTException.class)
public void IoTError() {

}
```

But when I try to convert to another homemade exception

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = IoTException.class)
public void IoTError() {
    throw new IoTConnectionException();
}
```

Exception handler is ignored, i.e. `IoTException` are sent to the view without being converted to `IoTConnectionException`. But placing a breakpoint showed me enter the `IoTError` method.
Any idea why ? Thanks :)

Comment: what is ignored? on IoTException.class you are not getting inside the @ExceptionHandler?

Comment: Edited the question to be more complete.

Comment: there is no conversion. IoTException.class gets you to the @ExceptionHandler where from you are throwing an exception. If you can see that the debugger is breaking inside the IoTError() are you saying that the exception is then not thrown?

Comment: Exception is caught by spring and interpreted as an error in the `ExceptionHandler`, so handler is ignored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [docs about exception handling](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers) state:

> If an exception occurs during request mapping or is thrown from a request handler such as an @Controller, the DispatcherServlet delegates to a chain of HandlerExceptionResolver beans to resolve the exception and provide alternative handling, which typically is an error response.

At the point where you are throwing the IoT exception, the delegation to the chain of *HandlerExceptionResolver* has already been taken place and it will not be executed again. If this exception would trigger another exception handling dispatch it could cause exception cycles. Imagine you would have defined another exception handler method for *IoTConnectionException* and this would throw *IoTException*. You would end with a *StackOverflowException*.

In this section [Docs Exception handler methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) all supported return values of an exception handler method are described.

Comment: You're right, my exception is interpreted as a error in the handling of the exception : `Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method`, instead of as another exception to handle

Comment: There was actually a `@ControllerAdvice` class I wasn't aware of with another `@ExceptionHandler` as you guessed. I moved my handler in this class and called the former handler instead of throwing the exception, and it worked !